# What is the matter with my microphone?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, audio, manjaro, microphone

My system recognizes the microphone of a webcam that connects via USB and also the microphone of a bluetooth headset, I decided to buy a new microphone because the audio from these devices is not to my liking. This new microphone connects through the usual jack port for microphones, and although the system recognizes that there is an audio capture device, when I use the microphone, nothing other than noise is distinguished (I have tested it on other devices and it works perfectly).

Is there an audio configuration, or a driver, that solves this?

This is the output of `inxi -Fazy`:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.10.15-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64 
  root=UUID=8fe00721-c979-4ea2-aa27-ae70dfd1dab5 rw quiet apparmor=1 
  security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.20.5 tk: Qt 5.15.2 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM 
  Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: TOSHIBA product: Satellite C50-A v: PSCJEM-015TM1 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: TOSHIBA model: Portable PC v: MP serial: <filter> UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.10 
  date: 12/03/2013 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 24.2 Wh condition: 35.0/47.5 Wh (74%) volts: 10.8/10.8 
  model: PA502 type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Charging 
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse serial: <filter> 
  charge: 55% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N2820 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Silvermont family: 6 model-id: 37 (55) stepping: 3 microcode: 31A 
  L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 8536 
  Speed: 2400 MHz min/max: 533/2399 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2400 2: 2400 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
  Type: mds 
  status: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass status: Not affected 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 
  mitigation: Full generic retpoline, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds status: Not affected 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display 
  vendor: Toshiba driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:0f31 
  class ID: 0300 
  Device-2: Importek TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  bus ID: 1-4.4:5 chip ID: 10f1:1a52 class ID: 0e02 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.10 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: 
  loaded: intel unloaded: modesetting alternate: fbdev,vesa display ID: :0 
  screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1280x720 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 338x190mm (13.3x7.5") 
  s-diag: 388mm (15.3") 
  Monitor-1: eDP1 res: 1280x720 hz: 60 dpi: 93 size: 350x190mm (13.8x7.5") 
  diag: 398mm (15.7") 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (BYT) v: 4.2 Mesa 20.3.4 
  compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio 
  vendor: Toshiba driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  chip ID: 8086:0f04 class ID: 0403 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.15-1-MANJARO 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8188ee 
  v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8179 class ID: 0280 
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Toshiba 
  driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 1000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8136 
  class ID: 0200 
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 275.56 GiB (29.6%) 
  SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required. 
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 
  size: 931.51 GiB block size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
  rotation: 5400 rpm serial: <filter> rev: 1U scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw size: 922.99 GiB size: 907.51 GiB (98.32%) 
  used: 274.66 GiB (30.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2 
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw size: 300 MiB size: 299.4 MiB (99.80%) 
  used: 280 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1 
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache pressure: 100 (default) 
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 8.22 GiB used: 913.8 MiB (10.9%) 
  priority: -2 dev: /dev/sda3 maj-min: 8:3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 218 Uptime: 8h 51m wakeups: 29 Memory: 3.73 GiB 
  used: 3.15 GiB (84.5%) Init: systemd v: 247 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 
  Packages: 1703 pacman: 1693 lib: 463 flatpak: 0 snap: 10 Shell: Bash 
  v: 5.1.0 running in: konsole inxi: 3.3.01
```

And the output of `pacmd list-cards`:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x90910000 irq 97"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "0f04"
                device.product.name = "Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Audio Interno"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Entrada Estéreo analógico (priority 65, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo: Salida Estéreo analógico (priority 6500, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Estéreo analógico dúplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Salida Digital Stereo (HDMI) (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Salida Digital Stereo (HDMI) + Entrada Estéreo analógico (priority 5965, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Salida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Salida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) + Entrada Estéreo analógico (priority 865, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Salida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Salida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) + Entrada Estéreo analógico (priority 865, available: no)
                off: Apagado (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#4: Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#5: Monitor of Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
                alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#6: Audio Interno Estéreo analógico
        ports:
                analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible do activate and deactivate

```
microfone, webcam and like this
```

on some PC, notebooks and like this,

```
on BIOS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible do activate and deactivate microfone and webcam on PC, notebooks and like this, on browser configuration p.e. on Firefox by:

```
* GUI
* about:config
```